# How to get module to automatically pass its name to another module without having to pass it as a prop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to refactor some code where individual modules have the same custom helper method. Rather than each of these modules having their own implementation of this helper method, I'm trying to move the method to a pre-existing helper module and then importing it to each module that needs it. The universal method should manage state inside a `this.components` object.

Below is a simplified example, and each code snippet is inside of a class. In reality, the helper method is used in a lot of places, and a small change to how it works will require many changes elsewhere.

**Helper method (example)**

```js
setComponent = (component, label) => {
  this.components.push({component, label});
}
```

I can import and use like this.

```js
import { setComponent } from './helpers';

...

setComponent(this.button, 'example');
```

I also want to be able to delete all components that were set for a specific module. For instance:

```js
removeComponents = module => {
  // remove components by module
}
```

```js
import { removeComponents } from './helpers';

...

removeComponents('moduleName');
```

The problem here is that `this.components` needs to be passed a module name each time `setComponent` is called so that it has a key to be used as a way to remove the right components in `removeComponents`. `setComponent` would need an extra `module` argument.

```js
setComponent = (component, label, module) => {
  this.components.push({component, label, module});
}
```

While that works, it creates a problem of bloat in each of the modules. Now every time `setComponent` is called, it has to pass the same module name each time.

```js
setComponent(this.a, 'example1', 'thisModule');
setComponent(this.b, 'example2', 'thisModule');
setComponent(this.c, 'example3', 'thisModule');
setComponent(this.d, 'example4', 'thisModule');
setComponent(this.e, 'example5', 'thisModule');

...
```

The module name argument could be abstracted away, and each module could use a local method that passes the local module name along with the component data object to `helper.setComponent`.

```js
import { setComponent as helperSetComponent } from './helpers';

...

// use local setComponent method to pass component data to
// helper's setComponent along with this module's name
setComponent = (component, label) => helperSetComponent(component, label, 'thisModule');

...


this.setComponent(this.button, 'example');
```

But now I'm back to square one. In trying to use a universal method, I have to create a local handler method to make everything work.

**Is there another vanilla JS way to do this that won't create any extra code bloat in the process, and that doesn't introduce React/Redux/Angular/Vue, etc.? Open to ESnext possibilities.**

**edit**: curry function suggestion by Bergi

In local modules:

```js
// local helper function
setComponent = helperSetComponent(component, label)('thisModule');
```

In helper file:

```js
setComponent = module => (component, label) => {
  this.components.push({component, label, module});
}
```

Comment: No, you will need a local helper function, but you could construct it by simply calling a curried function instead of declaring a wrapper function

Comment: @Bergi I edited the question and added a curry example. Is that right? Thanks for the help

Comment: Rather `const helperSetComponent = setComponent('thisModule');`, then use it multiple times as `helperSetComponent(this.e, 'example5')`

Comment: aaaaaaaah cool. That's awesome. Had to test that out to get it. Thank you